# Problems while adding multiple reactions to a message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm having problems while adding multiple reactions to a message (trying to add 8-9).

Basically, the script adds the reactions normally if you wait, but if you react to a emoji before the scripts add them all, it keeps trying to add the rest of the emojis even after the message already got deleted, throwing the error below.

```
(node:17500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\#######\Documents\project-folder\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

So, any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```
// Context

message.channel.send({ embed: randomEmbed }).then((msg) => {
  msg.react(emNumber[0]).then(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < dcArr.length && !msg.deleted; i++) {
      if (dcArr[i]["server_id"] == user.server_id) continue;
      msg.react(emNumber[i + 1]);
    }
  });

  var filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return (
      emNumber.slice(0, dcArr.length - 1).includes(reaction.emoji.name) &&
      user.id === discId
    );
  };

  msg
    .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 20000, errors: ["time"] })
    .then(async (collected) => {
      msg.delete();
      message.channel.send({ embed: anotherRandomEmbed }).then((msg) => {
        msg.react(emThumbs[1]);
        msg.react(emThumbs[0]);

        // Something

        var filter = (reaction, user) => {
          return emThumbs.includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === discId;
        };

        msg
          .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 20000, errors: ["time"] })
          .then(async (collected) => {
            // Something else
          });
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, and I don't think you can do anything about but adding `if (!message.deleted)` before every reaction add

Comment: Any way I can tell the script to stop the loop if that happens and move on?

Comment: `if (!message.deleted) message.react() else <stop the loop>` or something like that

Comment: Oh yeah, I tried that, script breaks regardless